# NodeFlow - How to connect Properties in a clean way?

Tags: c#

[image: Image of the first implementation of NodeFlow]

I have implemented a project called **NodeFlow**. As you can see in the picture you can create multiple **nodes** and connect their **properties** with other (Function)Nodes to modify the properties and let the data flow through the nodes to create a result (in this case it is the addition and multiplication to the result 4). I implemented NodeFlow in similarity to the Node Editor in the 3D Software *Blender*.

You can see that NodeFlow is somewhat working, but I am very unhappy about my architecture. So I decided to implement the application in a better way and it would be great if you could tell me what you think. However, I am only providing interfaces because I am right now creating the architecture of my application and I want to discuss this architecture with you.

---

**What do you need to know about the nodes?**

```
public interface INode
{
    string Name { get; set; }

    NodeTypes Type { get; set; }

    bool HasInputProperties { get; }

    bool HasOutputProperties { get; }

    ObservableCollection<IValueAcceptorProperty> ValueAcceptorProperty { get; set; }

    ObservableCollection<IValueProviderProperty> ValueProviderProperty { get; set; }
}
```

#### More Explanations

The **node** is the thing you see in the picture as "Constant Value: 1", "Add Function" and "Multiply Function". Nodes contain a Name, Input and Output Properties. I called these properties in my code `ValueProviderProperty` and `ValueAcceptorProperty` because calling it **Input** and **OutputProperty** was very confusing while coding and because value providing properties (or output properties) can only be connected with value accepting properties (or input properties) you have a data flow in one direction. That means that the `ValueAccpetorProperties` are taking (or accepting) the value of the connected `ValueProviderProperty`.

---

**Properties**

```
public interface IProperty
{
    string Name { get; set; }

    PropertyDataTypes AllowedDataTypes { get; set; }

    IConnector Connector { get; set; }

    INode ParentNode { get; set; }

    bool HasValue { get; }
}

public interface IValueProviderProperty : IProperty
{
    // This is like Variant
    IPropertyValue Value { get; set; }
}

public interface IValueAcceptorProperty : IProperty
{
    // This is like Variant
    IPropertyValue Value { get; }
}
```

**Property Code:**

This implements the `ValueAcceptorProperty` to show how I want to use this interface. As you can see the `ValueAcceptorProperty` is just forwarding the `Value` of its `ValueProviderProperty`.

```
public class ValueAcceptorProperty : IValueAcceptorProperty
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IPropertyValue Value
        => this.Connector.IsConnected
            ? this.Connector.Connection.ValueProviderProperty.Value
            : null;

    public PropertyDataTypes AllowedDataTypes { get; set; }
    public IConnector Connector { get; set; }
    public INode ParentNode { get; set; }
    public bool HasValue => this.Value != null;
}
```

Every property has a `Connector` (the visual of it is the circle next to each property) and the `Connectors` are connected via a `Connection`.

**Connector and Connection:** (These are in separated files)

```
public interface IConnection
{
    IConnector ValueProviderConnector { get; set; }

    IConnector ValueAcceptorConnector { get; set; }

    IValueProviderProperty ValueProviderProperty { get; set; }

    IValueAcceptorProperty ValueAcceptorProperty { get; set; }
}

public interface IConnector
{
    bool IsConnected { get; set; }

    IConnection Connection { get; set; }
}
```

Most of the missing definitions for `PropertyDataTypes` and so on are enums or other data structures which are in my opinion not that important to discuss the general idea of NodeFlow.

So my main Questions is: **Do you think that there is a better way to model the Nodes, Properties, Connections and Connectors?**

If you need further information I will update this question to provide whatever you need.